# How can I generalize an ApiKeyAuthenticator in Symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have the following code that checks whether the API-key is the correct one before sending data to the front end.

`file1Controller.php`

```
<?php


namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class file1Controller extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     * @Route("/Some/URI", methods={"GET"}) // "/Some/URI" here
     * @param Request $request
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function list(Request $request)
    {
        if (empty($request->headers->get('api-key'))) {
            return new JsonResponse(['error' => 'Please provide an API_key'], 401);
        }

        if ($request->headers->get('api-key') !== $_ENV['API_KEY']) {
            return new JsonResponse(['error' => 'Invalid API key'], 401);
        }

        return new JsonResponse($this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('App:Something')->findAll()); //Something here
    }
}
```

Which works excatly as intended (tested it with Postman) for my simple learning example. I would like to generalize it so that I can use it in other places. Almost everything should stay the same except the parts where there are comments. I have tried the following:

`General.php`

```
<?php


namespace App;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;


class General extends AbstractController
{

    private $request;
    private $route;
    private $entity;

    /**
     * ApiKeyAuthenticator constructor.
     * @param Request $request
     * @param String $route
     * @param String $entity
     */
    function __construct(Request $request, String $route, String $entity)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->route = $route;
        $this->entity = $entity;
    }

    /**
     * @Route({$route}, methods={"GET"}) //notice here
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function list()
    {
        if (empty($this->request->headers->get('api-key'))) {
            return new JsonResponse(['error' => 'Please provide an API_key'], 401);
        }

        if ($this->request->headers->get('api-key') !== $_ENV['API_KEY']) {
            return new JsonResponse(['error' => 'Invalid API key'], 401);
        }

        return new JsonResponse($this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('App:{$this->entity}')->findAll()); //notice here
    }

}
```

Then I change the code of `file1Controller.php` to:

```
<?php


namespace App\Controller;

require(__DIR__.'/../General.php'); //note that there's no error accessing the file here
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class file1Controller
{

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function AuthenticateAPI(Request $request)
    {
        $AuthenticatorObject = new ApiKeyAuthenticator($request, "/Some/URI", 'Something'); //getting undefiend class 
        return $AuthenticatorObject;
    }

}
```

This is unfortunately not working when testing it with Postman and I'm getting an undefiend class error on this line `$AuthenticatorObject = new ApiKeyAuthenticator($request, "/Some/URI", 'Something');` in `file1Controller.php`

What did I do wrong and how could I fix it?

Comment: Could it be something wrong with Postman itself?

Comment: @Doesitmatter No. The code is not even compiling within PHPStorm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't call your controllers like this in Symfony:

```
require(__DIR__.'/../General.php'); //note that there's no error accessing the file here
```

Please check out defining and accessing controllers as service in Symfony documentation:

[How to Define Controllers as Services](https://symfony.com/doc/master/controller/service.html)

[How to Forward Requests to another Controller](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/forwarding.html)

Comment: Everything in src folder will use `App` namespace. for example if there is `HelloController` you should use `use App\Controller\HelloController;`

Comment: where is `General.php` file located?